# SSL (https) in python tornado

Tags: python, https, ssl-certificate, tornado

I created both certificate file and key file by:

```
openssl req  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout ho-madad.1.pem -out ho-madad.2.pem
```

I received both file successfuly. I put both files at root of my Python project.

In PyCharm I have this code:

```
import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import http.server


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
    if self.request.protocol == "http":
        self.redirect("https://%s" % self.request.full_url() 
                 [len("http://"):], permanent=True)

def get(self):
    self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/t", MainHandler),
])

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application,
    ssl_options = {

    "certfile": os.path.join("ho-madad.2.pem"),
    "keyfile": os.path.join("ho-madad.1.pem"),
    }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server.listen(443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But when I am running from browser with `https://ho-madad/t`
I am receiving this error:

```
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(356, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File >"C:\Users\nisim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\asyncio\events.py", 

line 145, in _run   self._callback(*self._args)

  File "C:\Users\nisim\Documents\EPM>ServerSideCode\EmpServerSide\venv\lib\site-ackages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py",

 line 122, in _handle_events   handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "C:\Users\nisim\Documents\EPM >ServerSideCode\EmpServerSide\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", 
line 300, in null_wrapper   return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nisim\Documents\EPM >ServerSideCode\EmpServerSide\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line >262, in accept_handler   callback(connection, address)
  File "C:\Users\nisim\Documents\EPM >ServerSideCode\EmpServerSide\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line >263, in _handle_connection do_handshake_on_connect=False)
  File "C:\Users\nisim\Documents\EPM >ServerSideCode\EmpServerSide\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line >565, in ssl_wrap_socket context = ssl_options_to_context(ssl_options)
  File "C:\Users\nisim\Documents\EPM >ServerSideCode\EmpServerSide\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 540, in ssl_options_to_context
    context.load_cert_chain(ssl_options['certfile'], ssl_options.get('keyfile', >None))
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3393)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default output of `openssl req` is a certificate *signing request* instead of a certificate. Add the `-x509` option to generate a self-signed certificate, or submit the signing request to a certificate authority of your choice to get a signed CA.